# Slow transaction processing in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have been noticing a bad behavior with my Postrgre database, but I still can't find any solution or improvement to apply.

The context is simple, let's say I have two tables: CUSTOMERS and ITEMS. During certain days, the number of concurrent customers increase and so the request of items, they can consult, add or remove the amount from them. However in the APM I can see how any new request goes slower than the previous, pointing at the query response from those tables as the highest time consumer.

If the normal execution of the query is about 200 milliseconds, few moments later it can be about 20 seconds.

I understand the lock process in PostgreSQL as many users can be checking over the same item, they could be even affecting the values of it, but the response from the database it's too slow.

So I would like to know if there are ways to improve the performance in the database.

The first time I used PGTune to get the initial settings and it worked well. I have version 11 with 20Gb for RAM, 4 vCPU and SAN storage, the simultaneous customers (no sessions) can reach over 500.

Comment: You have to find out which queries are slow and why. Set `log_lock_waits = on` in `postgresql.conf`, reload and look at the log file.

Comment: There is not enough info here to say anything.  Try using auto_explain and/or pg_stat_statements to identify slow queries.

Comment: In the absence of sessions, what does a "simultaneous customer" mean?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm taking a look at the possible logs after this change.

Comment: @jjanes Those are plain selects, no joins. With simultaneous I meant concurrency, imagine 20 users trying to get the same item.

Comment: Well, 20 is a lot less than 500.  Nothing good is going to come from letting 500 connections be *active* simultaneously, unless you have 500 CPUs, or 500 drives in our storage subsystem.  Now they have to do the same work, but also have to do the extra work of fighting each other for safe access to the resources.

Comment: @jjanes You misunderstood my explanation, when I said 500 I was referring to users in the application, not sessions on the database. But from those, could in fact exist 20 sessions pointing to the same table ITEMS. The database will never reach that ammount of direct connections.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe more like slow execution queries, I found queries waiting. For example a delete waiting for about 3 seconds before being executed

Comment: Waiting for what? Did you see the lock in `pg_locks` or the `wait_event` in `pg_stat_activity`?

Comment: "ShareLock on transaction" and "AccessExclusiveLock on tuple"